# Health Check for Down stream service

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, microservices, health-monitoring

I want to write health check all my down stream services which is consumed by our services. we can write easily for GET Methods, it won't affect anything. but how to do it for POST / PUT Methods as it changes the existing values ?

Comment: You may want to look at https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix and read http://blog.christianposta.com/microservices/comparing-envoy-and-istio-circuit-breaking-with-netflix-hystrix/  They discuss circuit breakers.   There are also read-write caches such as Apache Ignite.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements in your domain you may have different expectations from a health check. Possibilities are:

1. Service running. You call just one method of the service to check the return code only. You only want to ensure that the whole service has not crashed, etc. This is the most common form of health check.
2. Functionality specific. This is what your idea sounds like - The service is called and the return parameters evaluated.
3. Full test. The service is called with the same test coverage as before deployment is authorized.
4. Service Internal. The service offers a special endpoint for health checks that gives a detailed view of the service health.

In most distributed systems a health check is performed on the service level only (option 1) and in this case it doesn't matter which endpoint is chosen and sometimes it doesn't matter what the return is (could be an error for example, as long as it is not a timeout).

The deeper the scope of the test, the more time execution will take and the less frequent you will be able to perform it.

The most thorough health check would be a full unit test (for example posting/changing and deleting different sets of data). However, if that is not desirable for performance impact you could rely on one of a few things:

1. Post/put with illegal parameters. Just to check if the service returns the expected error code (as compared to timeout for example).
2. Implement a test mode in your service, e.g. though passing a special parameter or with a special endpoint that could run an internal test.
3. Have services implement a business purpose, so that the complete service never only has POST/PUT methods, but also GET. And then you only use the GET to determine service health.